# Authenticate to google API

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-authentication

I have a google account, whom has a registered application, and access to it's own drive.

I want to create a server to server application.

My server authenticates to google server and creates a file in the drive.

How does my server has to authenticates itself to google's server ? What is the workflow ?

Note : since my server is in fact salesforce's one, I have no ip to authorize nore any url to redirect to ... Plus I won't be able to use any wrapper or plugin. Hence I'm looking for a fully http request based solution.

Answer (score 0):

seems like I found myself an answer : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount